# How to isolate a variable when its on both sides of equation

Tags: linear-algebra

$ ex-1=x $

How do rearrange this equation to isolate x 
i.e in the form of x=.....

Comment: Subtract $x$ from both sides of the equation.

Comment: Just to clarify:  is your question about $e$ **times** $x$ or $e^x$?

Comment: Thanks guys, I have edited for clarity.
Definitely e times x

Comment: If in your question it is the term $e^x$, then for the equation you have you will need to use the Lambert W function if you wish to solve explicitly for $x$ in closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
ex-1=x \\
ex-x-1=0 \\
x(e-1)=1 \\
x= \frac{1}{e-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the $x$'s to one side of the equation and the constants to the other side.  You can move the $x$'s to the left side and constants to the right.  Then you will have $ex-x=1.$  Now just factor out the $x$ from the left side, that is $$xe-x=1\iff x(e-1)=1$$
Then divide both sides by $e-1.$  This gives you $x=\dfrac{1}{e-1}.$